# mvc application calendar is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have creating MVC application where I added calendar on textbox and this is working in Chrome but not in IE. Here;s the code.
HTML Code:-

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("Date of Request")
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa- 
calendar"></span></span>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateOfRequest, new {@class = "form- 
control", @placeholder = "Form Name", @title = "Form Name", type = 
"date"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateOfRequest, "", new 
{@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
        </div>
```

Model.cs

```
 [Display(Name = "Date Of Request")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfRequest { get; set; }
```

Its is working in Chrome, Edge but i need to make it work n IE9, IE11. My organization is using only IE. I tried everything, but nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateOfRequest, new {@class = "form-  control
 datepicker", @placeholder = "Form Name", @title = "Form Name", type = 
 "date"})
```

I added datepicker in class then it worked well